# Parse JavaScript from remote server using curl

Tags: php, curl

I need to grab a json-string from this page: `https://retracted.com`

If you view the source, I json-string starts after `var mycarousel_itemList =`. I need to parse this string as a correct json-array in my php-script.

How can this be done?

EDIT: I've managed to pull this off using `explode`, but the method is ugly as heck. Is there no build-in function to translate this json-string to a array?

To clarify: I want the string I grab (which is correct json) to be converted into a php-array.

Comment: Do you have permission from the copyright owner?

Comment: Yes I do. I work for a company making a collaborate homepage for this bank and this estate-selling-company. We were trying to fetch this information using their api, but they use so long to respond, so I figure I could just rip it from their homepage. And again, to clarify; I do have permission.

Comment: And your username is OptimusCrime . . . :)

Comment: @Adam Hopkinson, You don't need permission to parse a site.

Comment: @Optimus1 apart from when you do

Comment: @ Adam Hopkinson, I never needed permission ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON in the script block is [invalid](http://jsonlint.com/) and needs to be massaged a bit before it can be used in PHP's native [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) function. Assuming you have already extracted the JSON string from the markup (make sure you exclude the semicolon at the end):

```
$json = <<< JSON
[ { address: 'Arnegårdsveien 32', … } ]
JSON;

var_dump(
    json_decode(
        str_replace(
            array(
                'address:',
                'thumb:',
                'description:',
                'price:',
                'id:',
                'size:',
                'url:',
                '\''
            ),
            array(
                '"address":',
                '"thumb":',
                '"description":',
                '"price":',
                '"id":',
                '"size":',
                '"url":',
                '"'
            ),
            $json
        )
    ,
    true
    )
);
```

This will then give an array of arrays of the JSON data ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9j2r4c)).

In other words, the properties have to be double quoted and the values need to be in double quotes as well. If you want an array of `stdClass` objects instead for the "{}" parts, remove the `true`.

You can do this either with `str_replace` as shown above or with a regular expression:

```
preg_match('
    (.+var mycarousel_itemList = ([\[].+);.+function?)smU',
    file_get_contents('http://bolig…'),
    $match
);
$json = preg_replace(
    array('( ([a-z]+)\:)sm', '((\'))'),
    array('"$1":', '"'),
    $match[1]
);
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

The above code will fetch the URL, extract the JSON, fix it and convert to PHP ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NDlbIX)).

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your json data, you can use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) (PHP >= 5.2) to convert it into a PHP object or array

Comment: In the updated question, it says he's managed to pull this off (out?) using `explode`, "*is there no build-in function to translate this json-string to a array?*"

Comment: json_decode cannot decode the string though. string is broken.

Comment: @adam : I managed to do what I wanted, but I had to use 5 explodes and a few loops. I was just wondering if I could avoid this